# Pagination together with a html form

Tags: php, mysql, forms, pagination

On my website I use a pagination (similar to that one on the bottom of this page) for MySQL output. For the change of the current page I use `GET` method (variable page) and it works well. 
However, on my page I have also a form, using method `POST`, which acts as a filter for the MySQL output. This rises a problem because, when I change the form settings an submit them (`POST`), the page in the address line (`GET`) remains the same. This is problem in some cases when the filtered output has less pages than that one currently set.

Is it somehow possible to set the page variable to 0 always when the form is submitted? 
Particularly, I did it using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'`. However, this changes just the variable in the code. Not at the address line. 
On the other hand I want to keep the `POST` variable when I change the page of the output.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: its not clear what is the current behavior and what are you trying to achieve. assuming you want to submit the form AND keep the pagination - just add a POST parameter which will state on which page of the results you're in.

Comment: yep, maybe it's not clear. I tried to keep the text short. In fact, I want to redirect the page to www.something?page=0 after each submission of the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a logical collision in your setup:
Unlike GET method, POST method doesn't keep variables in the address bar. But for some reason you are using POST method.

So, the solution is quite simple - use GET method for the filtering.

To create pagination links use `http_build_query()` out of `$_GET` array

Comment: Thanks, I think so. I will check the use of http_build_query().

Answer (score 0):

In fact it's better to send filter criteria in the address (GET method). It will solve your problem with pagination and you (and your users) will have a direct link to search results.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I was just thinking about the same way. I think, it should be easy to do. The direct link to the result is also a good point.Thanks again :)

Answer (score -1):

In your PHP code, you want to redirect to the URL with the page GET parameter removed if you are SUBMITTING (by pressing the "Filter" button, or whatever it's called).  So it will start at page 0.

You would have to rewrite the URL yourself (or using a plugin).

Typo corrected, I meant page 0, not 1 :P

Comment: Yes, something like that. After the submission of the form I would like to go to www.something.php?page=0.